# Log in DD-WRT router via SSH works, web front end does not

Tags: ssh, passwords, dd-wrt, root

I can use SSH to log in as the root user, but the same credentials are not logging me into the front end.  What is going on here?

Comment: Obviously, the SSH service has nothing to do with the web service, they are run by different processes. By accessing the SSH service, you have only made sure that you can access the router, so there're no network issues. What's not working with the web front-end? What kind of error are you getting? You need to supply more information.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. I wasn't getting any error, it just wasn't authenticating me using the same credentials I used to successfully in via SSH.  Solution is outlined below.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is wrong, but since you have the SSH password you can re-set the password to the webadmin like this:

```
setuserpassword user password
```